# JavaFX scene does not resize to fill stage if stage has minWidth/minHeight set

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I need to set a minimum width and minimum height on a given window.

I've found that if I do so then the Scene does not fill the parent when the window is first shown. If you manually stretch the window it repaints correctly.

This only appears to occur when minWidth = width AND minHeight = height. It all other cases it is resized as expected (say for example minWidth = width -1).

Additionally this only appears to occur on Linux, specifically Red Hat 6, and only on Java 8.
I can't find any existing bug report for this behavior.

I'm looking for a workaround to this problem. This is a legacy project and unfortunately updating Java is not possible.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SceneDoesntFillStage extends Application {

    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);

        primaryStage.setMinHeight(200);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);

        HBox root = new HBox() {
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                super.layoutChildren();
                System.out.println("Layout");
            }
        };
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
        root.setPrefWidth(250);
        root.setPrefHeight(150);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        System.out.println(primaryStage.getScene().getWidth() + " x " + primaryStage.getScene().getHeight());
    }

}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: I can reproduce this by calling `primaryStage.sizeToScene()`. If the root node has no width/height set, it's not even visible until I resize the window. Also, the minimum size I'm able to set the stage to is 284x161 which makes no sense to me. Couldn't find a workaround yet (except not calling `sizeToScene()` )

Comment: One workaround is to call `root.setPrefWidth(primaryStage.getMinWidth()); root.setPrefHeight(primaryStage.getMinHeight());` but I don't know if that makes sense in your context.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but anyway... You can try this one:

```
root.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
root.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
```

And also remove this:

```
root.setPrefWidth(250);
root.setPrefHeight(150);
```